# Backup restore without content in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I want to take a backup of my existing site and restore it on a different Sharepoint server. I know its easily possible through stsadm backup restore. But I dont want the content of my lists to appear in the restored sites. Is there any way to achieve this using backup or export command????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a site template and choose NOT to include content.

Site Actions > Site Settings > Look and Feel > Save site as Template

See this guide

- [SharePoint Site Templates: KISS guide to creating, saving and using](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/04/sharepoint-site-templates-kiss-guide-to-creating-saving-and-using/)

Comment: Yeah i know this can be achieved through site template but it does not preserve the people and groups and permissions. Besided what i want to is that I want content of 7 lists to appear and content of 56 lists not to appear in the restored site.

Comment: You might have mentioned that in your Question, my mind reading skills are not so good today <sigh>... Some of the tools mentioned here may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967882/what-are-sharepointmoss-2007-developement-deployment-best-practices/2968713#2968713